# How to sort a list of trending Hashtags by activity?

Tags: tags, hashtag, sliding-window, trend

What is the right way to sort a list of e.g. hashtags by activity?

I collect the hashtags by counting the occurrence of a tag in the last 1000 messages that were posted. Then I have a dictionary like this:

```python
{"hashtag": 12, "tag": 11, "some": 6, "thing": 4, "yet": 2, "another": 2, "word": 1}
```

Sorting purely by number does not help to identify trends. Maybe people are talking everyday about "hashtag", so it does not mean there is a trend in it. And with real data you often get a static top 10, that rarely contains a new tag.

So it should account for changes in the frequency of the tags. But with a sliding window of 1000 posts, the trends "slide in" as well, so you will not see jumps that can be identified as "starts trending".

What is the correct criterion to identify when some hashtag or word starts trending in a stream of messages?

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: It's python, but that should not be relevant to the question. The data structure is a `dict` or in other languages a `map`. The question is about how to extract trends from this data and not specific to python only. So if you have a solution, e.g., for javascript, I can adapt it for my code.